# Get all followers and friends of a Twitter user

Tags: python, mongodb, twitter

I'm trying to find my bug or any potential bottleneck that cause my program to be really slow. The script is to get all the followers and friends and save that in MongoDB.

```
import pymongo
import tweepy

consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True, retry_count=3, retry_delay=60)

db = client.tweets

raw_tweets = db.raw_tweets
users = db.users

def is_user_in_db(user_id):
    return get_user_from_db(user_id) != None

def get_user_from_db(user_id):
    return users.find_one({'user.id' : user_id})

def get_user_from_twitter(user_id):
    return api.get_user(user_id)

def get_followers(user_id):
    users = []
    page_count = 0
    for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, id=user_id, count=200).pages():
        page_count += 1
        print 'Getting page {} for followers'.format(page_count)
        users.extend(user)
    return users

def get_friends(user_id):
    users = []
    page_count = 0
    for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends, id=user_id, count=200).pages():
        page_count += 1
        print 'Getting page {} for friends'.format(page_count)
        users.extend(user)
    return users

def get_followers_ids(user_id):
    ids = []
    page_count = 0
    for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, id=user_id, count=5000).pages():
        page_count += 1
        print 'Getting page {} for followers ids'.format(page_count)
        ids.extend(page)

    return ids

def get_friends_ids(user_id):
    ids = []
    page_count = 0
    for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends_ids, id=user_id, count=5000).pages():
        page_count += 1
        print 'Getting page {} for friends ids'.format(page_count)
        ids.extend(page)
    return ids

def process_user(user):
    user_id = user['id']
    screen_name = user['screen_name']
    print 'Processing user : {}'.format(user['screen_name'])

    the_user = get_user_from_db(user_id)
    if the_user is None:
        follower_ids = get_followers_ids(user['screen_name'])
        friend_ids = get_friends_ids(user['screen_name'])

        user['followers_ids'] = follower_ids
        user['friends_ids'] = friend_ids

        users_to_add = []
        for follower in get_followers(screen_name):
            if not is_user_in_db(follower.id):
                users_to_add.append(follower._json)

        for friend in get_friends(screen_name):
            if not is_user_in_db(friend.id):
                users_to_add.append(friend._json)

        users.insert_many(users_to_add)
        users.insert_one(doc['user'])

if __name__ == "__main__":

    for doc in raw_tweets.find({'processed' : {'$exists': False}}):
        print 'Start processing'
        if 'user' in doc:
            process_user(doc['user'])

        if 'retweeted_status' in doc:
            process_user(doc['retweeted_status']['user'])

        raw_tweets.update_one({'_id': doc['_id']}, {'$set':{'processed':True}})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `is` to compare to `None`, as that's [faster](http://jaredgrubb.blogspot.ie/2009/04/python-is-none-vs-none.html).

```
def is_user_in_db(user_id):
    return get_user_from_db(user_id) is None
```

You can also use list concatenation rather than `list.extend` as [it's slightly faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3653339/4374739) and there's no benefit to `extend` in this context. I also second the recommendation to use `enumerate` rather than having a manually incremented number in a `for` loop.

```
def get_followers(user_id):
    users = []
    page_count = 0
    for i, user in enumerate(tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, id=user_id, count=200).pages()):
        print 'Getting page {} for followers'.format(i)
        users += user
    return users
```

When you have a local variable here, use it instead of a dictionary call. It's quicker to access than a key.

```
screen_name = user['screen_name']
print 'Processing user : {}'.format(screen_name)
```

You can also collapse these lines by assing the results of the function calls directly.

```
    user['followers_ids'] = get_followers_ids(screen_name)
    user['friends_ids'] = get_friends_ids(screen_name)
```

You can make a list comprehension out of `users_to_add`, it's a single line of code that more efficiently creates a list based on a for loop-like construct. So this:

```
    users_to_add = []
    for follower in get_followers(screen_name):
        if not is_user_in_db(follower.id):
            users_to_add.append(follower._json)

    for friend in get_friends(screen_name):
        if not is_user_in_db(friend.id):
            users_to_add.append(friend._json)
```

Can be turned into this:

```
    users_to_add = [follower._json for follower in 
            get_followers(screen_name) if not is_user_in_db(follower.id)]
    users_to_add += [friend._json for friend in
            get_friends(screen_name) if not is_user_in_db(friend.id)]
```

Also, it's more efficient to call dictionary keys, assuming they're there and handle the exception if they're not, like so:

```
try:
    process_user(doc['user'])
except KeyError:
    pass

try:
    process_user(doc['retweeted_status']['user'])
except KeyError:
    pass
```

You could replace `pass` with something else if you'd like, but this is more efficient as the `if` statement in your script would check the dictionary to see if a key exists, and then check it again to get the actual value attached to the key. The `try except` way only checks once, and moves on if it gets nothing.

One final note, you'd be surprised how expensive frequent `print` calls are. You have ones running in loops. I don't know how often the loops run, but if you are experiencing sluggishness, try removing them to see what difference it makes. Feedback is obviously important, but speed is also important.

Comment: On that note about `print` If I change it to be `log` would that be better? I do need feedback as the number of followers could be more than 100k

Comment: @toy I did a quick check with Python's `timeit` module. If I run `print("This is a test")` 10,000 times in the interpreter, it takes 20 seconds (that can vary based on where you're reading your output). If I run `file.write("This is a test")` 10,000 times it takes 0.01 seconds. So using a log function is likely a good bet.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid `page_count = 0`, and incrementing it. I suggest `enumerate` to reduce verbosity.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont require the twitter usernames of the followers and friends, you can just collect their twitter ids. That makes the code way faster.